# document.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize,.. never called; firefox

Tags: firefox, events, resize, three.js

I have a issue with the resize event that bothers me for some time now. I im using three.js 69 with firefox.

I added those to the event listener:

```
document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
document.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false);
```

( mousemove works normally...I added it just to show that nothing else is wrong with the code before )
The function is:

```
function onWindowResize(){
console.log("resize");}
```

Now when i resize the window i get:
Error in parsing value for 'height'. Declaration dropped. meni.html
This error is dumped ONCE EVERY time i resize the window.
The console.log message is not shown ( function is not executed ).
I'm stuck with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add resize event listener to window, not to document.